# How can I set up a batch process for watermarking and printing pdf files?

Tags: pdf, batch, adobe-acrobat

I want to automate a process of applying individual watermarks to and printing a fair number of .pdf files. My main program for handling .pdf files is Adobe Acrobat Pro XI. Acrobat has a feature called "Actions" which can be used for batch processing, including applying watermarks, but there is no way to specify in advance individual watermarks for each file with this feature. Thus, some kind of custom script seems like the natural solution.  Acrobat supports JavaScript, but I don't know exactly how to utilize it.

In short, what I need to do is this: Based on one list file(.txt file or excel/.csv) with corresponding numbers *A* and *B*, and one separate list file with the filename(s) of the document(s) to be printed for each number *A*, apply an individual watermark "B" on each file, and send the file(s) to the printer.

Is it possible to achieve this with Adobe Acrobat and JavaScript? If not, what is the best way to go about it?

Preferably, the solution used should require low level of/no special system privileges and not be able to delete files/cause any other damage to the file system.

Comment: How many documents are you planning to process per day?

Comment: About 50 documents, once per week.

Comment: may write powershell script

Comment: @STTR: Would you care to elaborate?